# Capacitance with different dielectrics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, gauss-law

I have to calculate the capacitance of a spherical or a cylindrical capacitor (The problem contradicts itself) and the free charge density at any point of the inner conductor. The region between the conductors is filled with four diferent dielectrics. As it can see in the image:

[image]

The system has a potential difference $V_0$.

Really I have no idea how to do it, my idea was, at least for capacitance, to use the fact that $Q = C\Delta V$ and, by Gauss's law, $Q = (\oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s})\varepsilon_0$.

However, I think it is difficult to get the electric field with that information. Besides, I don't know how to represent the different permittivity of dielectrics.

Answer (score 2):

Consider them as four different capacitors in parallel connection, therefore, calculate the capacitance of each part separately and add them to get the equivalent capacitance of the system.
You can easily calculate the voltage using the expression for electric field which would be
$$E=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon}\frac{q}{r^2}$$
Where $q$ is the charge on the particular part of the plate, and $\epsilon$ is the value of permittivity in the specific dielectric used.
The charge should cancel out, and you should be getting the capacitance of the four individual parts, now just add them to get the equivalent capacitance.

Comment: It's not obvious that this is correct without the approximation $b/a-1\ll 1$; the picture suggests that $b/a-1\approx1.5$.  But I can't tell for sure that it is incorrect either.